# How to format a string with a width and a literal?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have Python (2.7) code which takes a float, formats it with thousand-separating commas and 3 decimal places, and adds the string literal " sec" afterwards.

The result is then formatted further by being aligned left and given a width of 20:

```python
num = '{:,.3f} sec'.format(1200300.4443333333)
print '{:<20}'.format(num) + 'more'
```

Ouput:

```
1,200,300.444 sec   more
```

I wanted to condense this into a single `format` call, but I couldn't figure out how to use the width properly with the string literal.

I tried the following:

```python
num = '{:,.3f}'.format(1200300.4443333333)
print '{:<20} sec'.format(num) + 'more'
```

But the output isn't the same:

```
1,200,300.444        secmore
```

I also tried the following:

```python
num = '{:,.3f}'.format(1200300.4443333333)
print '{:<20 sec}'.format(num) + 'more'
```

But that failed:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    print '{:<20 sec}'.format(num) + 'more'
ValueError: Invalid conversion specification
```

Is there any way to condense the initial code into a single `format` call?

Comment: I do not think you can solve this with one call to `format`.

Comment: @DYZ Unless you use `ljust`, but that's kind of a workaround.

Comment: This isn't going to be possible in one statement because you want the 20 width to apply to the whole number + the string. The best is going to be nested format calls like `print("{:<20} sec".format("{:,}".format(1200300.4443333333)) + " more")`

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if it is but the following code might be what you're after:

```
num = '{:<20,.3f} sec more'.format(1200300.4443333333)
print(num)

# 1,200,300.444          sec more
```

Comment: Not OP's desired output.

Comment: Let OP decide that?  It's one very simple line, and it might achieve their goal

Comment: No thousands separator and the spacing is all wrong here.

Comment: The thousand separator is very easy to add (added).  Maybe let the person who asked the question decide if the spacing suits them, only he/she knows if they can be flexible on it.  It's obvious this is a slightly modified output, but since it meets the one line demand, it might suit the needs of the person who asked.  And even if it doesn't, it might help somebody else reading this page later.